# asp.net: explicit localization & combining strings

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, localization

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I can't figure it out.

I have a localized resource that I'm using in two places - one as a col. header in a datagrid, and then as a descriptor beside a field when the user edits a row.

The text of the label looks like:

```
Text="<%$Resources:Global,keyName%>"
```

However, I'd like to add a trailing : to the label - except if I change the above to

```
Text="<%$Resources:Global,keyName%>:"
```

then the : is the only thing that shows up!  I've tried it with simple strings, so there's nothing special about the colon char that causes this.

Surely I don't have to have 2 different resources?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Text="<%$Resources:Global,keyName%>" + ":" ?
You'd basically be concatenating two strings.  Or treat them as two strings

```
StringBuilder t;
t.append(<%$Resources:Global,keyName%>)
t.append(":")
Text = t;
```

Comment: Tried the first suggestion, didn't work.  But that was a clue to what should have been obvious - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to keep the : together for styling reasons, replace the label with a span:
    <%=Resources.Global.keyName %>:

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes the obvious isn't so obvious until someone else looks at it:

```
Text="<%$Resources:Global,keyName%>" /> :
```

Just move the : outside the label tag, and all is well.

Comment: True, that's so obvious it's not even funny.  It's one of the downsides of the "tag soup" when mixing back-end code with html